# Automatically add to DOM when there is new updates

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an HTML page where DOM element will automatically update when there are new comments added to the database.
Here is the HTML code

```
    <h1 id="name" style="text-align: center"></h1> 
    <h2 id="singername" style="text-align: center"></h2>
    <textarea id="content"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" id="submitreview" onclick="submitreview()">submit</button>
```

Here is the Javascript code to add review to the database when click submit:

```
    async function submitreview() {
        var selectedone = localStorage.getItem("category");
        var selectedtwo = localStorage.getItem("song");
        const reviewcontent = document.getElementById("content");
        var d = new Date();
        e = d.toLocaleString();
        g = userID;
        namelist = [];
        await db.collection("User").doc(g).get().then(function(doc3) {
            if (doc3.exists) {
                console.log(doc3.data().name_user);
                namelist.push(doc3.data());
            } else {
                console.log("nothing here exist");
            }
                }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
        var username = namelist[0].name_user;
        db.collection("Song").doc(selectedone).collection("songs").doc(selectedtwo).collection("reviews").doc().set({
            review_content: reviewcontent.value,
            review_date: e,
            user_id: userID,
            user_name: username,
        })
        document.getElementById("content").value = "";
    }
```

Here is the javascript code to load DOM elements base on the data from database:

```
async function foo() {
        var selectedone = localStorage.getItem("category");
        var selectedtwo = localStorage.getItem("song");
        var contentresult = [];
        await db.collection("Song").doc(selectedone).collection("songs").doc(selectedtwo).collection("reviews").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc2) {
                    console.log(doc2.id, " => ", doc2.data());
                    contentresult.push(doc2.data());
                    // console.log(doc2.data()[1].review_date.todatestring());
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                });
                console.log(contentresult);
        const reviewlist = document.getElementById("reviewlist");
        for(let b = 0; b < contentresult.length; b++) {         
            var node = document.createElement('div');

            var size = document.createElement('h2');
            var size2 = document.createElement('h2');
            var size3 = document.createElement('p');
            var breakpoint = document.createElement('br');
            var anotherbreakpoint = document.createElement('br');

            size.setAttribute('class','left');
            size2.setAttribute('class','right');

            var text1 = document.createTextNode(contentresult[b].user_name + ' - ');
            var text2 = document.createTextNode('- ' + contentresult[b].review_date);
            var text3 = document.createTextNode(contentresult[b].review_content);

            size.appendChild(text1);
            size2.appendChild(text2);
            size3.appendChild(text3);

            node.appendChild(size);
            node.appendChild(size2);
            node.appendChild(breakpoint);
            node.appendChild(anotherbreakpoint);
            node.appendChild(size3);

            reviewlist.appendChild(node);

            }
    }
```

Right now, I have to reload the page every time I add a comment to see the updates on the page, how can I make it synchronize with the updates from the database. I use Firestore as the database.

Comment: Is the db firestore?

Comment: Yes, I am using firestore

Comment: Are you getting real time updates from the database with this code?

Comment: No, I only get it when it loads the page. Should I add the listener and will it work?

Comment: If you add the listener, it will work. But there is another way. Just call function `foo` in the end of `submitreview`. I think it'll be enough

Comment: after adding a new document just fetch the collection again.

Comment: Oh, it works when I call the ```foo``` function in ```submitreview```. Thank you

Comment: I'm gonna update this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real time fetching going on with this code. If you add an listener, it will work. But there is another way. Just call function foo in the end of submitreview. I think it'll be enough. Happy to help :)